# How to provide types for variable in closure?

Tags: julia

I would like to generate a function `f`, which keeps a variable `a` in its closure, like the following:

```
function g(a::Vector{Int})
    gf = quote
        x = $a
        function test() 
            b = 0
            for i in eachindex(x)

                b += i
            end
            b
        end
    end
    eval(gf)
end

f = g([1,2,3,4])

@code_warntype f()
Variables:
  b::ANY
  #s41::ANY
  i::ANY

Body:
  begin  # In[21], line 6:
      b = 0 # In[21], line 7:
      GenSym(0) = (Main.eachindex)(Main.x)::ANY
      #s41 = (top(start))(GenSym(0))::ANY
      unless (top(!))((top(done))(GenSym(0),#s41)::ANY)::ANY goto 1
      2: 
      GenSym(1) = (top(next))(GenSym(0),#s41)::ANY
      i = (top(getfield))(GenSym(1),1)::ANY
      #s41 = (top(getfield))(GenSym(1),2)::ANY # In[21], line 9:
      b = b + i::ANY
      3: 
      unless (top(!))((top(!))((top(done))(GenSym(0),#s41)::ANY)::ANY)::ANY goto 2
      1: 
      0:  # In[21], line 11:
      return b
  end::ANY
```

As you can see, `f` is a bit inefficient as type inference is unable to tell the types of `i`, `b`, which I suspect due to missing type inference of `a`.

Is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `eval` is called within function `g`, it evaluates `gf` in the global context. In the global context type inference is harder for variables. Defining values as `const` improves the situation. In your example:

```
function g(a::Vector{Int})
    newvar= gensym("t")
    gf = quote
        const $newvar = $a
        function test() 
            b = 0
            for i in eachindex($newvar)
                b += i
            end
            b
        end
    end
    eval(gf)
end
```

gives better typed variables. From `@code_warntype f()`:

```
Variables:
   b::Int64
   #s2::Int64
   i::Int64
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I have to declare `const` somewhere, but didn't realize I can put `const` inside quote